# Why does Win 10 Desktop Window Manager use so much memory 5+GB

Tags: windows, windows-10

Why does Windows 10 Desktop Window Manager consume so much memory? What is it doing with all that RAM? I have 16 GB of RAM and DWM is consuming 5+GB of it.

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and add more detail to try and narrow it down, including what you've investigated already, and what the results were.  Perhaps check out: http://superuser.com/questions/212407/why-does-desktop-window-manager-leak-memory-or-even-crash, and http://superuser.com/questions/428794/why-is-dwm-exe-using-so-much-memory

Comment: can you repro this? if yes, open a cmd.exe as admin, type **wpr.exe -start CPU -start ReferenceSet -filemode && timeout -1 && wpr.exe -stop C:\HighMemoryUsage.etl** capture 5 minutes of the grow until you press a key to stop tracing. Zip the HighMemoryUsage.etl + PDB folder and share it (Onedrive share link)